# Why incompatible version of Java EE error throw from WebSphere?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ant, websphere

I was using WebSphere Allication Server version 7.0.0.13 in deploying my application. The war was build using Ant version 1.8.2 to build the war and ear file. When I am installing my application through WebSphere, I hit the following error:

> The EAR file could be corrupt and/or incomplete. Make sure that the
> application is at a compatible Java(TM) Platform, Enterprise Edition
> (Java EE) level for the current version of WebSphere(R) Application
> Server.
>
> com.ibm.websphere.management.application.client.AppDeploymentException
> [Root exception is org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException:
> dd_in_ear_load_EXC_]

May I know what cause the problem? Or did I miss configure something in Ant script? Below are the ANT script for compiling the WAR and EAR.

```
<target name="compilewar" description="generating war">
        <war destfile="${dist.path}/WebApp.war" webxml="${source.path}/mywebapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <webinf dir="${source.path}/mywebapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/" includes="**/*"/>
            <lib dir="${dist.path}/" includes="*.jar"/>
            <classes dir="${source.path}/mywebapp/src/main/resources/" includes="**/*"/>
            <fileset dir="${source.path}/mywebapp/src/main/webapp/">
                <include name="**/*.jsp"/>
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="${source.path}/mywebapp/src/main/webapp/">
                <include name="main/**/*"/> 
            </fileset>
        </war>
    </target>

<target name="compileear" description="Compile Ear file">
        <ear destfile="${source.path}/myear/src/main/application/WebApp.ear" appxml="${svn.working.project.path}application.xml">
            <metainf dir="${source.path}/mywebapp/src/main/webapp/META-INF"/>
            <fileset dir="${dist.path}/" includes="*.war"/>
        </ear>
    </target>
```

THanks @!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the problem solved. This is due to the missing **source** properties in javac ant task. As mention in the ANT documentation for **source** properties:

> Note that the default value depends on the JVM that is running Ant. We
>   highly recommend to always specify this attribute.

It is recommended to specify the java version that going to be used for the compilation. Below is the sample usage on the source properties:

```
<javac source="1.6"/>
```

THanks @!

Answer (score 4):

@huahsin68: make sure you use WAS JDK to compile classes which you are packaging as part of your war file. If you are using ant to compile too, ensure ANT use WAS JDK as java environment to run.

Server's systemout.log and startServer.log must have given more logs. Check that.

If you are using IDE like eclipse, set the project compliance level to J2EE1.5 and clean and re-build.

Comment: Thank you so much on consultation. I will look into that. BTW, I am using pure ANT script to do the compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are trying to deploy j2ee 1.3/1.4 compatible WAR/EAR in WAS 7 which supports Java EE 5. Check your application.xml and web.xml to see if you are using the correct schema versions. Also check IBM specific deployment descriptors. I [found this link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK78515) on WAS support website.

Comment: You mention the schema versions thing, this could be the clue for me to move on the search. May I know how to check the j2ee version that I am currently have in my web.xml and application.xml?

Comment: @huahsin68 check the servlet specs

Comment: No, you won't get that error if you deploy J2EE 1.3/1.4 on WAS 7; it supports those levels. See http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rovr_specs.html

Comment: @dbreaux Thank you so much on the reference.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception when I was installing a simple EAR in whesphere: [Root exception is org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: dd_in_ear_load_EXC_] and the reason was that the WAR inside the EAR was unpacked. So, I built a new EAR with a packed WAR inside and It worked. In my case I am using MAVEN and the plugin is (observe tag **unpack** with **false** value)

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <configuration>
               <modules>
                  <webModule>
                     <groupId>com.javaen</groupId>
                     <artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
                     <uri>myWar.war</uri>
                     <bundleFileName>myWar.war</bundleFileName>
                     <contextRoot>/myWar</contextRoot>
                     <unpack>false</unpack>
                  </webModule>
               </modules>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
```

I hope this help you, regards